# C# Put string into TextBox

Tags: c#

I want to show the results of this code in my TextBox:

```
       string txtout1 = txtOrgText.Text.Replace(parm, txtTo.Text).ToString();
       txtout = txtout1;
```

I have a textbox, `txtOrgtext`, into which the user inputs text. I want to put some text into txtout now.
I have set txtout to ReadOnly and MultiLine.

When I try running my program, I get the following error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'   C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 45  25  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

I tried `txtout1.ToString()`, but nothing changes.

I also tried `txtout.Text = txtout1` and get this error :

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: 
Control 'txtout' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

I got an error because I used Threading, without Threading it works fine.

Comment: please indicate clearly when you edit your post...

Comment: This should help you out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you need to do is:

```
 txtout.Text = txtout1;
```

This is because `txtout1` is just a string of characters, while `txtout` is a full TextBox, with all the drawing and colouring and stuff like that.

I see that you were on the right lines with your first line of code - txtOrgText.Text - the `.Text` is used both ways - for reading and writing. (Or "looking" and "changing" is another way of putting it.)

You do this with a lot of other controls - a ComboBox, a Form (to set the caption), a DomainUpDown (the thing with the arrows on the right) to name a few.

The reason that "ToString()" doesn't work is that ToString() is making your string of text into a string of text! It doesn't turn it into a TextBox for you.

Comment: @person-b i get error Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtout' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
i removd all tostring but ...

Comment: Are you using a BackgroundWorker component or the Thread class? Try doing a Ctrl+F (find) for them. If not, can you post as much code as possible to http://pastebin.com please. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, and, by the way, sorry for the slow response - I'll check up a bit more often now ;)

Answer (score 4):

txtOut.Text = txtout1;

Answer (score 2):

First of all  `txtout = txtout1;` will not serve as txtout is a textbox and txtout1 is a string .You should use

txtout.Text = txtout1

ie .Text property of textbox says
***Gets or Sets the current text in System.Windows.Forms.TextBox*** 
and its type is string as your txtout1 is already a string there is no need 
to convert it again by using .ToString()