# How to display ComboBox selection in a TextBox in C#?

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox, label

I have built a form in C# where I want to display the ComboBox selection in a TextBox. I know it sounds very simple but I keep getting errors.

For example, if the user selects "California" from the drop down menu, I want the TextBox to display "California". I have tried the following code for the ComboBox but haven't had any luck. Any help is appreciated!

```
cmb.SelectedItem = txt1.Text
```

Or

```
cmb.Text = txt1.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
string selected = this.ComboBox.GetItemText(this.ComboBox.SelectedItem);
```

to get the `string` of the selected item from the ComboBox. Then you could use:

```
textbox.Text = selected;
```

to set the TextBox text.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15186131) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1217774).

Comment: You could try `string selected  = combobox.Items[combobox.SelectedIndex].ToString();` or `string selected = combobox.Text;`, although, the latter isn't as preferred.